# Meteor Spawn Error ENOENT

Tags: meteor, docker

My fear is that in the docker server, it does not have access to the command, or there is an issue with MUP's installation, but I assume I am missing something? (I am using MUP to deploy).

I am trying to run:

```
  var assimp = spawn('assimp',['export','monster.gltf','monster.dae']);
  assimp.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('' +data);
  });
  assimp.on('close', function(code){
    console.log('Assimp exited with code ' + code);
  });
```

I sadly get an error:

> Error: spawn assimp ENOENT
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:189:32)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:355:16)
>       at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:458:9)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:413:17)

I have run `sudo apt-get assimp` The command does exist on my $PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to install the process from scratch on the server if it didn't exist....